# Native spell-checker not working on all sentences in Texlipse

Tags: comments, spell-checking, percentage, texlipse

Why does the native spell-checker of Eclipse not work in the following sentence?

```
$10\%$ of all natives like exotic spices from the neighboring countries.
```

Answer (score 0):

The native spell checker of Eclipse together with Texlipse seems to not check lines with a percentage sign in them, whether they are escaped or not. If you first write a line with an error and comment it out later, the wrong spelling is still marked. If you first write the percentage symbol and then your comment, it will not be checked. If you happen to have an escaped percentage symbol in your sentence, the rest of the sentence is not spell-checked.